# [docplex error]-docplex.mp.utils.DOcplexLimitsExceeded: **** Promotional version. Problem size limits (1000 vars, 1000 consts) exceeded

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I want to use docplex module in python and I have installed CPLEX version 20.10 and installed python 3.7.9.

When I tried to run the code, I got the error:
docplex.mp.utils.DOcplexLimitsExceeded: **** Promotional version. Problem size limits (1000 vars, 1000 consts) exceeded, CPLEX code=1016

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your model is too big for the [free CPLEX community version](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-free-ibm-cplex-alex-fleischer/) and you should move to an academic or professional version.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. That's really helpful.

Comment: I am wondering how I can install the academic version?